# Python - sending constant serial data from scale widget

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi new to this forum and programming in general. i have a project that requires the value from a tkinter scale to be sent over the serial port every second. I have been pulling my hair out trying to find the answer to this one. any advice would be appreciated. thanks :-)

edit - when running the bellow I am getting a tkinter window with the scale but up on moving the scale the data is not being pushed over the serial port.

```
import serial
from tkinter import *

mGui = Tk ()
mGui.geometry(500x250)

ser = serial.Serial(,'/dev/ttyUSB0',9600)
def scale1():
ser.write(s.get)
s=Scale (mGui, from_=0, to=100, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=scale1)
s.pack()
```

Comment: Hey @LeeWright! Welcome to SO. Please update your question to show what you've already done, which results you're getting and why it's not what you expected. That will increase your question quality, letting other users with your same problem find it and make it more attractive for people to answer it. Enjoy!

Comment: Awesome! now it's going to be easier for someone to understand your problem... good luck!

Comment: there's an error in the Serial constructor... you have a typo on the question, right? where it says `,/dev/ttyUSB0'` it should say `'/dev/ttyUSB0'` right?

Comment: yer sorry that was a typo!

Comment: hey Lee, just remember to indent code properly, cheers

Answer (score 0):

What you want is either an async or threaded producer/consumer pattern, essentially the serial port needs to be polled regularly for new incoming data, and written to regularly for outgoing data.

A generic example of this can be gleened from the stdlib Queue module. You could easily modify this such that when Scale()'s value changes, it puts the new value in the queue - and have a dedicated thread that reads new data (if available) or writes values that're in the queue to the serial port.

What you might run into is that if you move the Scale control very fast is that the queue will get more values in it than can be written in a timely fashion.

If thats the case, you might want to just skip the queue entirely and just make the serial read/writer work by always writing Scale()'s current value at a regular interval (0.02 second delay is probably the smallest you can get, but if you're really connecting @ 9600 baud just modify the write interval to not write more than you can physically put into the serial buffer's UART.

```
def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        do_work(item)
        q.task_done()

q = Queue()
for i in range(num_worker_threads):
     t = Thread(target=worker)
     t.daemon = True
     t.start()

for item in source():
    q.put(item)

q.join()       # block until all tasks are done
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Its going to take me a while to understand all that. As I say I'm new to all this. Any chance you could explain what each part of this code dose so its a little easier to understand? Thanks again